# Composer equivalent of npm's scripts.start

Tags: npm, composer-php

`npm` lets you have something like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node app.js",
  }
}
```

Then when you type `npm start` it'll start your app, with whatever command-line options you want. This provides a uniform entry point for all node apps.

Is there anything like that for Composer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a [custom](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands) `"scripts"` block just like in `npm`, but you don't need to preface the command with `run` when running the commands. e.g.

```
{
    "name": "vendor/project",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

With this, you can now run `composer test`.

N.B. if you create a script with the same name as a "native" command, you will see this warning:

> A script named about would override a native Composer function and has been skipped

However, you can still run the script via `composer run-script <script>`.

Answer (score 3):

Composer fire events based on various state, and this event can be intercepted and manage for execute script.
Generally the script are implemented as PHP class but you can launch command, as example, you can lauch `phpunit` command on `post-update-cmd` :

```
{
    "scripts": {
           "post-install-cmd": [
                 "phpunit"
              ]
    }
}
```

If you would like to [run the scripts for an event manually](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#running-scripts-manually), you can launch the command:

```
composer run-script post-install-cmd
```

[Check the doc for the complete reference](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)

Comment: Those are cool, but there's nothing you can run manually/directly is there?

Comment: Hi @Mark sorry I don't understand your question in the comment... can you explain better what you mean?

Comment: I want a command like `composer start` that will start your app. Ideally it would be able to run any executables in your `vendor` folder too without having to install them globally.

Comment: of course, you can [run scripts manually](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#running-scripts-manually)

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I wanted. And it even adds the bin-dir to the top of the PATH. Could you add that to your answer so that I can accept it please?

Comment: The [custom commands](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands) bit was what I was most interested in, but close enough.